# integrating a function through a for loop with appending an array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to perform an integration through a for loop to generate values for each range but cannot figure out how to append the array at the end.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import scipy.special as special

def func(m):
    return m**-1.35

mass=np.zeros(49)

for i in range(1,50):
    x=mass=integrate.quad(func,i,i+1)
    mass.append(x,i)
```

Comment: Use a list, `mass=[]` and `append(x)`.  And don't asign to `mass` in the loop.  In other words, do ordinary list appens loop

Comment: remove `mass=` from `x=mass=integrate....` and keep `x=integrate...`. That's all.